# Image causing reflow after loading despite having set width and height?

Tags: css

I've noticed a behavior that confused me which that I've seen in both Chrome and Firefox: I have a flex container with two children, an image and a text div. The image I set for example purposes at `100px` width and height as to not cause reflow after the image loads.

```
.container {
   display: flex;
   width: 200px;
}

.resource-type-logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  // for completeness sake, despite it being default
  min-width: auto;
  // for illustrative purposes
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.text {
    margin-right: auto
}
```

However, on Chrome and Firefox, while the image is loading, it looks like this (measured from a screenshot taken while loading with width around `71px` and height `100px`):
[image]

After the image loads (has the correct width and height of `100px`):

[image]

From my measurements, I've noticed that I can get the exact same width as the preloading size if I set the image's `min-width: 0`.
In other words, if I set `min-width: 0` then the image (after load) shrinks to `70.67px` since the text wants to take up as much room as possible. But that's also the same exact width of the box before the image loads: `~71px`. I tested this out with multiple sizes and in Firefox and it seems to hold true in both browsers.

Setting `min-width:100px` fixes the reflow issue completely, as seen from this screenshot while the image is loading:

[image]

So my question is: why is it shrinking during load to the size of if the `min-width` were set to `0`? I thought that if I set a fixed pixel value for `width` and `height` then I would be fine with respect to reflow after load, but this seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Default for `flex-shrink` is `1` - maybe you should set that to `0` for your image here?

Comment: @CBroe thanks! From some preliminary testing that seems to work the same as if I set `min-width:100px`. But _why_ would that affect the behavior of the loading image size and not the post-loaded size?